# Redirect a single URL request to another domain

Tags: iis

I've checked other posts here and can't find anything matching my specific situation.

What I'm trying to do is this (with IIS).

I want visitors to my site, if they request this URL "http://www.example.com/EarlyRegistration" to be automatically redirected to "http://info.example.com/EarlyRegistration" however, that sits on a different server, so I can't simply do it via a virtual directory.

What steps do I need to follow to do this? I'm extremely confused trying to figure it out from MS's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urlrewrite module for IIS can help with this. Please see the documentation at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

I tried the following rule (obviously with my own urls at the time) and worked

```
    <rule name="Redirect for EarlyRegistration" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="EarlyRegistration" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://info.example.com/EarlyRegistration" />
    </rule>
```

What it does:
    matches the portion after the "/" in the URL to EarlyRegistration. If true, redirects. 
Make sure this is the first rule you have in the ruleset if you have others.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I'm saying confused me... I tried reading that page but it's over my head?  What steps specifically do I need to follow? When I tried following the steps on that page, I ended up breaking my site so that no pages loaded.  I just deleted the rule to get it all working again.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  I was missing a ^ at the start of my pattern... that wasn't clear at all!